# Matlab Binary Plot for Magnitude Representing the Whole 8 Bits

Tags: matlab, plot, binary, magnitude

I am trying to achieve a magnitude binary plot, where y shows the binary magnitude for the 8 bits.  Others have addressed this question through plotting individual bits, but the goal to show the whole 8 bits, represented as one number (i.e. 00000001 = 1), magnitude in binary form on the plot.

Here is the code:

```
     % Magnitude
     binMag = [00000001; 00000010; 00000100] 
% binary string representation of decimal 1, 2, 3
    % Tried to convert bin to a double
    binTodouble = str2double(binMag);
    figure;
    stairs(binTodouble)
```

Overall, my goal is to have a plot like the one below showing magnitude in binary.
    [image]

Comment: Binary representation for the number 3 is 11, not 100. In your code you apply `str2double` to an array that already contains doubles. You might want to input your binary representation as strings, and then use `bin2dec` to convert them to numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the idea from Cris Luengo into account, you'll get the following short script. I just wanted to add how to specifically set the `xticklabel` and `yticklabel` as you wanted it to have in your plot.

```
% Binary values
bValues = { '00000000', 
            '00000001', 
            '00000010', 
            '00000011', 
            '00000100', 
            '00000101' };

% Double values
dValues = bin2dec(bValues);

% Output
figure(1);
stairs(dValues, dValues);
set(gca, 'xtick', dValues, 'xticklabel', dValues);
set(gca, 'ytick', dValues, 'yticklabel', bValues);
```

[image: Stairs plot]